# Adicionar meses a uma data javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo um campo que recebe uma data, a partir dessa data ele deve somar 1 mês

```js
//Funcao das datas
function addData() {

//Pegar data Atual para somar
var currentDate = new Date();

//pegar data atual para exibir
var currentDate1 = new Date();

//Capturar Quantidade de meses
var meses = "1";
//Parse Int dos meses
var a = parseInt(meses);


//Adicionar meses 
currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth()+a);

//Trazer data Atual
currentDate1.setDate(currentDate1.getDate());

   

//Exibir data Atual
document.getElementById('data').value = currentDate1.toLocaleDateString();


//Exibir a data ja atualizada
document.getElementById('dataAtualizada').value = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Data</label>
<input type="text" id="data" value="">
<br>

<label>Data Atualizada</label>
<input type="text" id="dataAtualizada" value="">
<br>

<input type="button" onclick="addData()" value="Calc">
```

Eu peguei um código que adiciona mas a partir da data atual, eu preciso que ele capture a data que estiver no campo "text" e não a atual.

Exemplo existe um campo "text" com a seguinte data
Data
10/10/2018

Data atualizada 
10/11/2018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foi criado uma função para converter as datas:

```js
function parseDate(texto) {
  let dataDigitadaSplit = texto.split("/");

  let dia = dataDigitadaSplit[0];
  let mes = dataDigitadaSplit[1];
  let ano = dataDigitadaSplit[2];


  if (ano.length < 4 && parseInt(ano) < 50) {
    ano = "20" + ano;
  } else if (ano.length < 4 && parseInt(ano) >= 50) {
    ano = "19" + ano;
  }
  ano = parseInt(ano);
  mes = mes - 1;

  return new Date(ano, mes, dia);
}

//Funcao das datas
function addData() {

  var dataDigitada = document.getElementById('data').value;

  //Pegar data Atual para somar
  var currentDate =parseDate(dataDigitada);

  //pegar data atual para exibir
  var currentDate1 = new Date();

  //Capturar Quantidade de meses
  var meses = "1";
  //Parse Int dos meses
  var a = parseInt(meses);


  //Adicionar meses 
  currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + a);

  //Trazer data Atual
  currentDate1.setDate(currentDate1.getDate());



  //Exibir data Atual
  document.getElementById('data').value = currentDate1.toLocaleDateString();


  //Exibir a data ja atualizada
  document.getElementById('dataAtualizada').value = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Data</label>
<input type="text" id="data" value="">
<br>

<label>Data Atualizada</label>
<input type="text" id="dataAtualizada" value="">
<br>

<input type="button" onclick="addData()" value="Calc">
```